# How to remove a host permission from Chrome Extension (after update)?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

We have a Chrome extension in webstore that had host 'x' in the manifest (permissions field). Then we updated the manifest and changed from host 'x' to host 'y'. After the auto-update, the users are alerted about the new host 'y' permission, which is fine. But after the update the permission for host 'x' is not removed! So now we have hosts 'x' and 'y' in the updated extension.
Is there a way of specifying in the manifest to replace host 'x' with 'y'?

Answer (score 2):

No - the permission is permanently granted to the users that installed the older version. This is a [mechanism to prevent accidental permission removals](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35063612/934239). There's no way to wipe that outside reinstalling.

It's very hard for the end-user to notice though - they'll need to specifically click "details" in the extension list to see the granted permissions.

**New users will only get asked about, and will grant, permission for the host Y, so you shouldn't worry about it.**

Comment: Yes, It should be.  btw, just FYI, we have this issue(which is not yet confirmed) http://crbug.com/588516.